# Delete a list of directories stored in a file

Tags: delete, rm

I have a list of directories names in the following path

```
/home/list/list.txt
```

The directories are all in the following path

```
/home/directory/
```

How can I delete the directories contained in the list using the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing the directories are empty, I would say...

```
while IFS= read -r directory
do
   #rmdir /home/directory/"$directory"
   echo rmdir /home/directory/"$directory"
done < /home/list/list.txt
```

And once you see the `echo` works as you want it to work, uncomment the `rmdir`.

This loops sequentially through the content of `/home/list/list.txt` and stores the value of each line in `$directory`. Then, it performs the `rmdir` action.

Note the usage of double quotes to prevent errors if the names contain spaces. The `IFS=` and `read -r` are well explained in [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001),

---

If the directories are not empty and you are **completely sure** about what you are doing, use `rm -r`. You can then add `-f` to force (again: if you are sure) or `-v` to have a verbose output.

Answer (score 12):

start with

```
xargs -I{} echo rm -fr /home/directory/{} </home/list/list.txt
```

which just echo's the command to do, and if ok remove the echo.

Comment: `"/home/directory/{}"` might be a better idea.

Comment: @Hannu In this case they are not needed as xargs passes the filename as a single argument to the command. It is not interpreted by the shell. But you are right; in general it is a good idea to double or single quote args in scripts.

Comment: I'd call that "a special case", as the norm in bash is that unquoted stuff gets split. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You okay with Python?

```
from os import system
lines = open("/home/list/list.txt", 'rb').readlines()
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    currentline = lines[i]
    rmcommand = "rm -r " + currentline.strip('\n')
    system(rmcommand)
```

This will take the list, split the lines into an array, then issue a command for each index in the array. The `strip` is to get rid of the trailing new-line character, if one exists.

Comment: Why not go entirely python, once started?  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996628/3720510

Comment: Those still call system commands from the `os` library. I figured this way still shows the asker, who may be unfamiliar with python, the exact system command that most are used to. Also, I'm a fan of "Python ParKour" and try to make even simple things complex :P

Comment: To be honest this is a very clumsy python script.. You could use the python functions that call `unlink` directly, also `system` is now obsolete in favor of `subprocess`..

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` in a simple one-liner

```
awk '{system ("rm -r /home/directory/\""$0"\"")}' /home/list/list.txt
```

The command iterates over the entries in the input file and creates the `rm` command via `system`.

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to call an external command like `awk` to then call an external command `system` to perform something that bash does natively